# Kendo UI scheduler doesn't display data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am currently working on a kendoscheduler for a sharepoint list. I'm building off of [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline-night#).

I'm populating my demo with the data which is present at [this URL](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings), which I have mapped locally. The only difference between the article and my code is that their URL is `http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline-night` but mine is some JSON stored in a local file.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date("2013/6/12"),
            startTime: new Date("2013/6/12 08:00 PM"),
            endTime: new Date("2013/6/12 08:00 PM"),
            dateHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("<strong>#=kendo.toString(date, 'D')# - #=kendo.toString(kendo.date.nextDay(date), 'D')#</strong>"),
            eventHeight: 50,
            majorTick: 360,
            views: [ "timeline", "timelineWeek" ],
            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            dataSource: {
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {

                        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/Stomo/Ajax.aspx/GetDataForTimeline",

                    }                  
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "meetingID",
                        fields: {
                            meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                            title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                            start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                            end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                            startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                            endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                            description: { from: "Description" },
                            recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                            recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                            recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                            roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                            attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            group: {
                resources: ["Rooms"],
                orientation: "vertical"
            },
            resources: [{
                field: "roomId",
                name: "Rooms",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                    { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" }
                ],
                title: "Room"
            }]
        });
    });
</script>


Here is the response i am getting from my ajax call
[  
   {  
      "MeetingID":2,
      "RoomID":1,
      "Attendees":[  
         2
      ],
      "Title":"Meeting with customers.",
      "Description":"",
      "StartTimezone":null,
      "Start":"\/Date(1370865600000)\/",
      "End":"\/Date(1370872800000)\/",
      "EndTimezone":null,
      "RecurrenceRule":null,
      "RecurrenceID":null,
      "RecurrenceException":null,
      "IsAllDay":false
   },
   {  
      "MeetingID":3,
      "RoomID":2,
      "Attendees":[  
         1,
         2
      ],
      "Title":"Guided tour for the investors.",
      "Description":"",
      "StartTimezone":null,
      "Start":"\/Date(1370865600000)\/",
      "End":"\/Date(1370872800000)\/",
      "EndTimezone":null,
      "RecurrenceRule":null,
      "RecurrenceID":null,
      "RecurrenceException":null,
      "IsAllDay":false
   }]
```

Do you have any thoughts on how to make this work correctly?

Comment: I think you would need to add `dataType: "json"` in your `transport read` request.